# How to use Knockout JS within Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

### My problem:

I am attempting to write a small Knockout JS app within Magento 2, I'm struggling to initialise the app as when I use `ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel, document.getElementById("koTest"));` it breaks the Knockout used by Magento and throws this error:

```
Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

### I suspect it's because of:

I suspect this is because Magento 2 already uses `ko.applyBindings()` within `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap.js`. And as that doesn't specify a node I can't use `ko.applyBindings` again.

If I don't use `ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel, document.getElementById("koTest"))` in my code then my app doesn't initialise.

This makes me think I need to somehow use the `ko.applyBindings()` in knockout/bootstrap.js but I've no idea how, can anyone help? I have little experience with Knockout.

### My Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'ko'
    ], function(ko) {
        // This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
        function AppViewModel() {

            this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
            this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
            this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
                return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
            }, this);

            this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
                var currentVal = this.lastName();
                this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
            };
        }

        ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel, document.getElementById("koTest"));
    });
</script>

<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<div id="koTest">
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <p>Full name: <input data-bind="value: fullName" /></p>

    <button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Capitalise</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a tutorial here: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/knockout-js-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Simple method where you DO NOT need to use html templates

Thanks to Vinai Kopp I've finally got an answer to this, it is much simpler than my previous hacky workaround (I was cleaning nodes). All you need to do is define `'ko'` as a dependency and add your code inside a return function.

Below is a simple example that renders out some text passed in via JSON.

**`app/code/VENODR/MODULE/view/frontend/templates/knockout-example.phtml`**

Here we tell Magento the scope of our components (this must match `data-bind: "scope: 'example-scope'"` and pass any additional data. This could be the base URL, a simple message, pretty much anything you want. I've passed a string (PHP echo) as an example

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": "VENDOR_MODULE/js/knockout-example",
                    "exampleMessage": "<?= __('Hello Magento Stack Exchange!') ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
    <h2 data-bind="text: message"></h2>
</div>
```

And here we write our Javascript.

**`app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/knockout-example.js`**

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return function(config) {
        this.message = ko.observable(config.exampleMessage);
    }
});
```

#### Result

[image]

### ---------------------

## Method where you DO need to use HTML templates

If you want to use the HTML templating system within Magento2/Knockout (which I presume you will need for any significant pieces of work) there are a few changes you'll need to make compared to my simplified answer (below).

**If you don't require the template functionality then scroll down to my old simplified answer.**

The files I'm using for this example are:

- `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Cms/templates/knockout.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Cms/web/js/knockout-example.js`
- `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Cms/web/template/test.html`

### The PHTML template file

The only change to our PHTML template is the call to the `getTemplate()` function:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": "Magento_Cms/js/knockout-example",
                    "exampleMessage": "<?= __('Hello Magento Stack Exchange!') ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
    <h2 data-bind="text: message"></h2>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

#### The JS (component) file

There are a few changes you'll need to make to the JS file, I'll detail these below.

```
define(['ko', 'uiComponent'], function(ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            exampleMessage: 'Hello?',
            template: 'Magento_Cms/test'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this._super();
            console.log(this.exampleMessage);
            this.message = ko.observable(this.exampleMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

1 - Your return function now needs to extend the uiComponent module:

```
return Component.extend({
    ...
});
```

2 - You need to add an `initialize` function and call `this._super()`. `this._super()` will call the parent component's function with the same name. So in this instance I *think* it will call `initialize` of `uiComponent`.

```
initialize: function() {
    this._super();
    ...
}.
```

3 - **Optional** - You can also set some defaults for your component here, I think this is a good practice to follow as it makes your component easy to work with. When you reuse it you can either keep the defaults or if you want to customise it you can call it with new arguments without altering the component.

For example, if you look at defaults in the JS it sets `exampleMessage` to `'Hello?'` yet the page is rendering the text as `Hello Magento Stack Exchange!`. This is because I've overwritten `exampleMessage` in the PHTML file when I've called the component.

### The HTML template

I'm still to dig around and see what the HTML templates are capable of, I presume the features mentioned on the [Knockout JS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) can be used in here making them pretty flexible.

I have just added some lorem ipsum text for now, I will likely provide another question/answer once I've figured out what the HTML templates can do.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores assumenda beatae blanditiis culpa cupiditate doloremque, expedita ipsum iure magni minima modi molestiae nulla optio porro ratione reiciendis repellat soluta voluptatum!
```

### The result, and overwriting the defaults

As mentioned before you can see that I have overwritten `exampleMessage` within the template, you can see it working as the text reads `Hello Magento Stack Exchange`.

[image]

If I remove the override in the template file `exampleMessage` will return to it's default of `Hello?`. I did need to delete `var/view_preprocessed` and `pub/static/frontend` after changing this though. I presume Magento had cached the value.

[image]

Comment: This will work in Magento2.1

Comment: @Venkat - Do you mean you can now easily use Knockout without having to clean the node? Or that my fix does work in 2.1?

Comment: Your fix will work in 2.1 ?

Comment: For me bindings is worked but getting reference error for first input data binding

Comment: I think so as KnockoutJS doesn't seem to have changed much since 2.0.X - I haven't tried it in 2.1 though so I'm not 100% sure. Also make sure you do some thorough testing as I'm not sure if this is the best method, it's the only one I can find though.

Comment: @Venkat I have finally found the proper method, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @BenCrook, Thanks For this awesome reply and easily explain knockout js. now i want to pass array instead of the message so Can you please tell me how can i pass array?

Comment: @Sarfaraj Have you tried replacing the message with an array? Like `['1', '2', '3']`. It should pull into your JS file just like the message does.

Comment: @BenCrook, Yes i have tried but i can't understand that how to get that array in js file and use it with if else condition.
right now i'm trying to add this message in Magento_CheckoutAgreement files but it's not working,

Comment: You should be able to access it with `config.arrayName` replacing `arrayName` with whatever you have named it. I don't have the time to get a demo working sorry, maybe ask a new question about it and I'll try and help if I can find the time.

Comment: @BenCrook. Hi, can you please help me here? I tried but can't solve this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/267464/17154

Comment: @BenCrook thanks for the deep explanation. Just one question is that, in your first example. You have just used the variable this.message without component.extend so can we also use the multiple functions in js without component.extend? Like this return { fname:function(){ return "text"; }}

Comment: @Camit1dk - Correct. To use knockout the only module you need to require is `knockout` or it's alias `ko`. If you don't need any of the features added by UI components then don't add more complexity just because that's how Magento do it

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/seeni9589/Magento2/tree/master/Smart/Feedback

Custom Feedback form with the knockout js.
Hope it helps.