# Making selector available to ui component / philosophy

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, requirejs

You'd think that the selector `.el` in

```
{
    ".el": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": .....
```

would be made available to the ui component.

Instead, it's just thrown away, and the core Magento ui components end up hardcoding `.el` inside the js files.

For example, check out `minicart.phtml`, and you can see the following snippet:

```
....

{
    "[data-block='minicart']": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    },

    ....
```

However, `[data-block='minicart']` is never made available to the ui component, and instead in `minicart.js` Magento has hard-coded the selector:

```
miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']');
```

There seem to be many more instances like this in M2 CE 2.1.7..

This seems super strange to me, and is borderline misleading - what's the philosophy behind it?

Additionally, if I want to pass my selector to my ui component, without having to hardcode it - what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as for why Magento don't use it themselves I have no idea. It's rare all files follow best practices so don't always rely on them.

I've included an example taken from some work we've done on a quantity selector. Although this isn't using UI Components like your example you should still have access to `node`.

### How to pass the element through to the JS

**In your template:**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".js-quantity-selector": {
            "quantity-selector": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**In your JS file:**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return function (config, node) {
        console.log(node);

        ...
    }
});
```

I've gone into a bit more detail about UI Components and their JS on [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889).

Comment: After having a chat with Erfan it sounds like this doesn't work inside UI Components, damn it!