# Best source for Knockout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, learn-magento

As a beginner, can anyone tell me which is the best source to learn how the knockout js works in magento2?

I have tried learning from http://knockoutjs.com/ but it does not give the detailed idea for magento2 working.

You can also suggest the paid tutorials/videos, it would be fine for me.

Comment: https://inviqa.com/blog/using-knockout-js-magento-2 and https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_knockoutjs_integration/

Answer (score 4):

**KnockoutJs ebooks:**

1) [KnockoutJS by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010T266UQ) - I read this book. Really helpful.

2) [Mastering KnockoutJS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1783981008)

**Online Resources:**

1) http://knockoutjs.com/

2) Stack Overflow

**Magento Resource:**

https://devdocs.magento.com

https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_knockoutjs_integration/

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/troubleshoot/ui_comp_troubleshoot_js.html

Comment: thanks, and these books have reference for magento2 or it just for learning knockout?

Comment: Just for learning knockout Js, but after reading and practice https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010T266UQ/?tag=stackoverflow17-20. I'm pretty sure you can play with Knockout Js in Magento.

Comment: One more thing, no rush, we should keep calm and learn the basic knowledge about Knockout Js.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below resources to learn knockout js

**For Magento 2 Prospective** -

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/knockout-js-in-magento-2/

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-write-a-page-using-magento-2-knockout-js/

[How to use Knockout JS within Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2)

https://magehit.com/blog/write-a-page-using-knockout-js-in-magento-2/

**for advance learning :**

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/knockoutjs/index.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have gone through all these links but it does not give the detailed explanation/learning, I want to lean from the basics using small tutorials like http://knockoutjs.com/  have but for magento2 specially.

Comment: For magento 2 prospective my first link is better.

Answer (score 0):

By following http://knockoutjs.com/ , you only learning knockout JS not magento2. If you need to learn knockout used in magento2 then you will have to learn checkout of magento2.

As, knockout used in magento-checkout, You will have to learn checkout component of magento2.

Research on that and also follow links suggested by @Dsmagento.