# Magento 2 : pagination using knockout

Tags: magento2, pagination, knockout

I want to develop pagination of custom collection using knockout.

How to implement it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why need to close ??

Comment: That sounds pretty interesting and also doable but your question is a bit broad