# Questions about using knockout

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, customer-data

I would like add a feature to show a data like the "Welcome username".
So i searched about how it works and i followed [this tutorial](https://belvg.com/blog/customer-data-management-in-magento-2.html)

I'm blocked because i'm always getting the error `unable to process binding company()`

I created a model which represent a company, in my class extending SectionSourceInterface in the getSectionData method i return `['name' => 'test']` to test the feature.

I put this in my frontend/di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="company" xsi:type="string">Test\Company\CustomerData\Company</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

I add this my default.xml module layout :

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="welcome_msg" before="-" template="Test_Company::html/welcome.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I put this in my welcome.phtml :

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block
 */
?>
<p>Hello</p>
<!-- ko if: company().name  -->
    <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'company'">
        <span data-bind="text: new String('<?=$block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'))?>').replace('%1', company().name)"></span>
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "company": {
                    "component": "Test_Company/js/view/company"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and i put this in my company.js :

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.company = customerData.get('company');
        }
    });
});
```

Could you help me please to know what's wrong in my process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Calling company() outside the scope

You are currently calling `<!-- ko if: company().name  -->` outside the scope binding. Try changing it to this:

```
<li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'company'">
    <!-- ko if: company().name  -->
        <span data-bind="text: new String('<?=$block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'))?>').replace('%1', company().name)"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

Another alternative would be to move the scope binding higher up in the DOM, on the UL maybe.

### Possible issue with the property

It could also be because company is not a Knockout observable, I've not worked on Magento 2 for few months so take this with a pinch of salt.

1. Add Knockout as a dependency of your JS
2. Initialise this.company as a KO observable

That would look like this:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'ko'
], function (Component, customerData, ko) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.company = ko.observable(customerData.get('company'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think there is another reason Ben.  We call `company().name` outside the scope `data-bind="scope: 'company'"`?

Comment: Ooo yeah I didn't see that if statement, good spot. I'll update this answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks verry much i'll try it wednesday after the day off and i return to you if it works. Your solution about the outside the scope seems to be right, i remember i failed a copy/past of the declaration i founded in the Theme module in the header template file. Do you have some good documentations / tutorials about working with knockout ? I don't really understand everything about how it works. Thanks

Comment: I don't think anybody understands it that well. The official docs are slightly helpful and can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html) and I have written a tutorial [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889)

Comment: Thanks very much it works well :)

Comment: Glad to hear it @help, if the answer worked for you can you mark it as accepted please.