# How To Pass data from Helper Data to Knockout JS file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, helper, data, magento2minicart

How i can pass helper data to Knockout JS to show it on my html file. Actually i am working on minicart and  i want to show the product Qty as Dropdown and get value from Helperdata.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889 will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance this is your Block function where you get Helper Data:

```
 public function getConfigData()
   {
       return $this->helper->getHelperPrice();
   }
```

Then in your .phtml file where you add script tag for JS, do this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/path/to/js_file": {
                "price": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getConfigData() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and finally in your JS file (I've some extra code here):

```
define([
       'ko',
       'uiComponent',
       'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
   ], function (ko, Component, customerData) {
       'use strict';
       var subtotalAmount;
       var maxPrice = config.price; //here we set the helper value;
       var percentage;
       return Component.extend({
           displaySubtotal: ko.observable(true),
           maxprice: '$' + maxPrice.toFixed(2),
           /**
            * @override
            */
           initialize: function () {
               this._super();
               this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
           },
           getTotalCartItems: function () {
               return customerData.get('cart')().summary_count;
           },
          
       });
   });
```

Comment: That is not passing a value to a KO template, that is declaring a global JS variable which is a terrible idea and would not work if there was more than one price required on a page.

Comment: Then why don't you answer? Please let us know the right way to do it.

Comment: I already have here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889

Comment: Thanks, that added to my knowledge.

Comment: I've edited my answer, can you take a look now? @BenCrook

Comment: That's much cleaner. Hopefully Mevada can use a PHTML otherwise this won't work as x-magento-init does not work in HTML files.