# Mageto2 error Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am getting following erro

```
knockout.js:3277 Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

Below is the code

```
var instance = new viewModel(initialData);
                        if(typeof(document.getElementById("menueditor")) !='underfined' && document.getElementById("menueditor")[0]){
                            ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("menueditor")[0]);
                            ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("menueditor"));
                            //ko.utils.domData.clear(document.getElementById("menueditor"));
                        }
                        var koNode = document.getElementById('menueditor');
                        var hasDataBinding = !!ko.dataFor(koNode);
                        console.log('has data binding', hasDataBinding);
                        if (!hasDataBinding) { ko.applyBindings(instance, koNode);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to apply the bindings which Magento already does, within Magento 2 you should never do this.

You will need to research [UI Components](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=quick_search&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=ui%20componen) to see how to use Knockout within Magento 2.

A very basic component utilising Knockout looks something like this:

```
define([
    'ko'
], function (ko) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            exampleText: ko.observable('Hello')
        });
    }
});
```

Template:

```
 <div data-bind="text: exampleText"></div>
```

I've answered this in more detail on [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/how-to-use-knockout-js-within-magento-2/103889#103889).